# Is there a way to change preference screen text-size without creating a new layout?

Tags: android, preferencescreen

The only way i've found is to a) use text-scaleX in styles, which I like but it stretches the text or b) Make a new layout and change text-size there but I don't like that solution cause that requires having to redo colors and you can't use switches(? I'm pretty sure atleast). Any help is much appreciated!

**Heres my preferences screen:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Notifications">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="prefNotificationSwitch"
        android:title="Get notifications" />
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="About">
    <Preference
        android:key="prefAbout"
        android:title="The app"
        android:summary="Text about the app"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="prefVersion"
        android:title="Version"
        android:summary="1.0"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="prefFeedback"
        android:title="Send feedback">
    </Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

*you just have to create single layout which will be compatible for all screen sizes*

Comment: Yes but I still can't set it as sdp anywhere, can I?